# How to run a command with options and store exit code in a variable

Tags: powershell

Hello Stack Overflow experts

I am currently trying to run an exe file from a PowerShell script, and would like to store the exit code in a variable.

If run from the Windows command line on its own, the syntax is as follows:

`C:\MyProgram\mycommand.exe --option1=value1 --option2=value2 --option3=value3`

In Powershell, I can run the above using the call operator:

```
$myExe="C:\MyProgram\mycommand.exe"
$options = @(
                "--option1=value1"
                "--option2=value2"
                "--option3=value3"
            )
& $myExe @options
```

but I'm not sure how to assign the exit code returned by the exe file into a variable.

So far, this is what I have tried:

1. Tried the following syntax:

```
$myVariable | & $myExe @options
```

but the variable does not get assigned a value

2. Used Tee-Object

```
& $myExe @options | Tee-Object $myVariable
```

but I get a ParameterBindingValidationException error

3. Created a System.Diagnostics.Process object

```
$ps = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
$ps.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\MyProgram\mycommand.exe"
$ps.StartInfo.Arguments = "--option1=value1 --option2=value2 --option3=value3"
$ps.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $True
$ps.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = $False
$ps.Start()
$ps.WaitForExit()
```

which allows me to get the exit code by calling $ps.ExitCode, but the exe is not running correctly.
No errors are thrown, but it looks like the options are not being read correctly.

Any deas on how this can be achieved?

Comment: $lastexitcode should already contain it?

Comment: What makes you think the exe does not run correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the executable exits, PowerShell will populate the `$LASTEXITCODE` variable with the exit code:

```
$myExe="C:\MyProgram\mycommand.exe"
$options = @(
                "--option1=value1"
                "--option2=value2"
                "--option3=value3"
            )
$outputFromExe = & $myExe @options

return [pscustomobject]@{
  Program = $myExe
  ExitCode = $LASTEXITCODE
  Output = $outputFromExe
}
```